# Drawing image on JScrollPane

Tags: java

I'm writing simple RPG map editor in java. Unfortunately I have no idea how to draw image onto JScrollPane.
I've create class MyScrollPane extending JScrollPane, and implementing paint function. 
Everything is working fine, but JScrollPane doesn't scroll image. My question is how to force scrolling image. Thank you for any help you can provide in this situation.

Comment: Please include relevant code with your question. [Help: Asking Good Questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I don't think this is the right way. You should rather create a custom `JComponent`, set the `preferredSize` to whatever shall be the size of the map drawing area, implement its paint method and mouse listeners and what else you need for drawing those maps, and then put that component into an ordinary `JScrollPane`